# iOS framework to wrap existing framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to define a common framework in a project that provides an implementation-agnostic layer. For example, provide a protocol like `Analytics` and a set of methods/properties as its interface, and provide the implementation through a singleton object so different app targets would use the same implementation.

The issue is when importing the framework from within an app target, a compiler error occurs like so:

`import Core // Missing required module 'Firebase'`

What needs to be done?

In the `Podfile`, dependencies are installed only for the framework targets, not the app targets.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies should set to `Core.podspec` if you make framework manager by `Cocoapods`

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'Core'

  s.dependency 'Firebase'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS framework to wrap existing framework,You have astray when you have this idea, One framework depends on the other. put the depends framework together with it when you use it, not contain or wrap. Cocoapods provides a simple way, create a new warehouse containing the two dependent frameworks, The idea of the first floor is right.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a pod installation configuration issue.
Changed the installation targets and the hierarchy, and things were solved.